# Using ngAnimate on a Array of data

Tags: angularjs

I have made a basic carousel and and would like to use ng-animate to animate when entering and leaving each index in an array. The templates in Carousel.Data will soon contain html data. I would like to also know what would be the best way of passing html in an array so the user can click next and be presented with the next html template.

I have ng-animate loaded in the DOM with angular version 1.21 but I get an error when I try to inject the dependancy

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Here is what I have so far:-

```
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wajRog
```

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you try reorganizing the script references? Did that help?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell in CodePen but be sure that `angular.min.js` is loaded **before** `angular-animate.js`. Make sure the order is as follows:

1. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.9/angular.min.js
2. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.9/angular-animate.js
3. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.9/angular-touch.js

You can rearrange the resources in code pen by clicking the hamburger icon near each resources and clicking/dragging to the top. If i got to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate for example and open the plunker for anchoring. If you move angular-animate cdn script tag above angular.min.js, it will give an injection error.

Let me know if that works.